# Automatic index entry for multiword terms

Tags: indexing, xstring, imakeidx

I'm a lazy person. The less I type the better, so I'm trying to make a macro to automatically arrange index entries for multi-word terms (composed nouns actually).

Normally you'd have to type:

```latex
...some others exhibit \textbf{complex behaviour}\index{behaviour!complex}
```

I want to reduce it to

```latex
...some others exhibit \iterm{complex behaviour}
```

So I came out with the following macro [MWE]:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xspace,xstring,imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\iterm}[1]{%
    \def\myindex{#1}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{ }{%
        \renewcommand{\myindex}{\StrBehind{#1}{ }!\StrBefore{#1}{ }}%
    }{}%
    #1\index{\myindex}\xspace%
}
\begin{document}

some others exhibit \iterm{behaviour!complex}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

There's also an optional argument in case I must force an entry, and later on I might add code to deal with prepositions (e.g. `\iterm{world of LaTeX} → \index{LaTex!world of}`, but its solution is a particular case of the one above.

So far I'm getting the following errors

- `\renewcommand\myindex` and `\def\myindex`:

  - Use of @index doesn't match its definition
  - Argument of @firstoftwo has an extra }.
- `\edef\myindex` and `\protected\edef\myindex`:

  - Use of @xs@IfSubStr@@ doesn't match its definition
  - Argument of @firstoftwo has an extra }.
  - Paragraph ended before @firstoftwo was complete.
  - Too many }'s.
- `\protected\def\myindex` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

  - Causes no error but does not add the entry to the index
- `\let\myindex`

  - Missing control sequence inserted.
  - Too many }'s.

I'm 100% sure this is doable but haven't figured out yet. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to separate the splitting of the parts from the index making command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring,imakeidx}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\iterm}[1]{%
  #1%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{ }{%
    \StrBehind{#1}{ }[\secondword]%
    \StrBefore{#1}{ }[\firstword]%
    \index{\secondword!\firstword}%
  }{\index{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

some others exhibit \iterm{complex behaviour}

Another \iterm{term}

And finish \iterm{z}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not the most elegant solution coding-wise, but works like a charm! Thank you @egreg, thanks a lot. I'm starting to suspect you know all the answers.